# pyodbc error on OS X machine?

Tags: python, macos, pyodbc

I'm trying to do access the remote MS-SQL database from my OS X machine, with help of pyodbc and python. When I try to execute, it's showing an error like this

```
Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

The code I've written is:

```
import pyodbc

def createdatabase():
    driver = 'SQL Server'
    server = '00000000'
    db1 = 'Vodafone'
    tcon = 'yes'
    uname = 'user'
    pword = 'pwd'

    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', host=server,database=db1,trusted_connection=tcon, user=uname, password=pword)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Comment: You probably need to use 'FreeTDS' driver instead of 'SQL Sever'. Consider reading https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ConnectionStrings

Comment: You might also want to consider trying [pymssql](http://www.pymssql.org/) instead of pyodbc.

Comment: any common package is there for manage, mssql,mysql,postgres, and all

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your only problem, but the pyodbc.connect() string needs to be formed with semicolons like this:

```
DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=yoursqlserver.com;PORT=1433;DATABASE=yourdb;UID=youruser;PWD=yourpass;TDS_Version=7.2;
```

You'll also have to read up on setting up FreeTDS and unixODBC from a Mac. If you're specifying SQL Server instead of FreeTDS, I'm guessing you haven't set up your configuration in freetds.conf, odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini, which are required for connecting to SQL Server from non-Windows machines.

Comment: re: connection parameters - They were using the multiple-keyword-arguments way of calling the `connect` method, which does work, e.g., `connect(Driver="{SQL Server}", Server="192.168.1.23", ...)` instead of the one-long-string approach `connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=192.168.1.23;...")`.